# How do I make a basic column(vertical) chart in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying out d3js and I have a problem with getting my first basic column(vertical bar) chart work. The only thing I find a bit difficult to understand is the scaling thing. I want to make the x and y axis ticks with labels but I have the following problems:

First of all here is my data:

```
{
"regions":
["Federal","Tigray","Afar","Amhara","Oromia","Gambella","Addis Ababa","Dire Dawa","Harar","Benishangul-Gumuz","Somali","SNNPR "],
"institutions":
[0,0,34,421,738,0,218,22,22,109,0,456]
}
```

1. On the y-axis the values are there but the order is reversed. Here is the code:

   var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data.institutions)]).range([0, height]);

then I use this scale to create a y-axis:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
```

and add this axis to the svg element

```
svgContainer.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Institutions");
```

the problem here is that the y-axis start from 0 at the top and with 700 at the bottom which is OK but it should be in reverse order.

The other problem I have it the x-axis. I want to have an ordinal scale since the values I want to put are in the regions names I have above. So here's what I've done.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(data.regions.map(function(d) { return d.substring(0, 2); }))
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

then the axis

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(x)
                      .orient("bottom");
```

and finally add it to the svg element

```
svgContainer.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate( 0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
```

Here the problem is the ticks as well as the labels appear but they are not spaced out evenly and do not correspond with the center of the rectangles I'm drawing. Here is the complete code so you can see what's happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    d3.json("institutions.json", draw);

});

function draw(data){
    var margin = {"top": 10, "right": 10, "bottom": 30, "left": 50}, width = 700, height = 300;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(data.regions.map(function(d) { return d.substring(0, 2); }))
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);


    var y = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, d3.max(data.institutions)])
              .range([0, height]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(x)
                      .orient("bottom");    

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(y)
                      .orient("left");  

    var svgContainer = d3.select("div.container").append("svg")
                           .attr("class", "chart")
                           .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                           .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                          .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" +margin.left+ "," +margin.right+ ")");        

    svgContainer.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate( 0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    svgContainer.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 6)
                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Institutions");

    svgContainer.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data.institutions)
      .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i* 41;})
        .attr("y", function(d){return height - y(d);})
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function(d){return y(d);});

}
```

Comment: You should consider presenting your example code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or in a [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/). Makes it a lot easier for people to see what you're working on and to help you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put the code to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GmhCr/4/

Feel free to edit it! I already fixed both problems.

---

To fix the upside-down y-axis just swap the values of the range function arguments:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data.institutions)]).range([height, 0]);
```

Do not forget to adjust the code for the bars if you change the scale!

---

The source of the mismatch between bars and the x-axis can be found here:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.regions.map(function(d) {
        return d.substring(0, 2);}))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

svgContainer.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data.institutions)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i* 41;})
    .attr("y", function(d){return height - y(d);})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d){return y(d);});
```

You specify the padding for rangeRoundBands at 0.1 but you ignore the padding when computing the x and width values for the bars. This for example is correct with a padding of 0:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.regions.map(function(d) {
        return d.substring(0, 2);}))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0);

svgContainer.selectAll(".bar").data(data.institutions).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * x.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d);
    })
    .attr("width", function(){
        return x.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height -y(d);
    });
```

The padding determines how much of the domain is reserved for padding. When using a width of 700 and a padding of 0.1 exactly 70 pixels are used for padding. This means you have to add 70 / data["regions"].length pixels to every bar's x value to make this work with a padding.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! It's finally looking like what I want it to look like. The linear scale is very straight forward and it makes sense, but I just can't get my head around the ordinal scale. One thing that bothers me is in you original jsfiddle page there is no gap between the bars. How do I get that?